# Error code 110 when using Facebook SDK3 in Android

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am trying to send a request using facebook sdk from android.

This is how i do it:

```
private void sendInviteRequestDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("id", USER_ID);
        params.putString("to", "xxxx"); 
        showDialogWithoutNotificationBar("apprequests", params);
}

 WebDialog requestsDialog = (
                    new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(HelloActivity.this,
                            Session.getActiveSession(),
                            params))
                            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                        FacebookException error) {
                                    if (error != null) {
                                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                            Toast.makeText(HelloActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(HelloActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                                    "Network Error", 
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                                        if (requestId != null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(HelloActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                                "Request sent",  
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(HelloActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }   
                                }

                                })
                            .build();
            requestsDialog.show();
```

So, i am logged into fb, i can see my list of friends, post on my wall, but i cannot send a request to invite to my app. Same url used in web browser on computer works, but not in android app.
This is the error i receive:

```
An error occured. Please try again later.
API Error code: 110
API Error Description: Invalid user id
Error Message: Missing user cookie(to validate session user)
```

My Permissions are:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList(
            "publish_actions", "publish_stream", "offline_access", "email",
            "basic_info", "user_likes", "user_birthday", "status_update",
            "create_note", "share_item", "user_status");
```

I am very much lost at this moment, don't get this.
Any ideas would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I waste a lot of time, but already found a solution. Facebook problem is cache. I create method for get Session and clear cache is token is created from cache:

```
private Session getFBSession() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(getActivity());
        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        if (session.getState() == SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }

    return session;
}
```

But for you this is not enought, because closed session is not opened session. So you need after button push reopen Session:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Session session = getFBSession();

    if (!session.isOpened())
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(facebookForShareCallback));
    else
        session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, facebookForShareCallback);
}
```

And callback should be something like that:

```
private Session.StatusCallback facebookForShareCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("name", "name");
            params.putString("caption", event.title);
            params.putString("description", event.descLong);
            params.putString("link", "http://www.lt");
            params.putString("picture", event.logo);

            WebDialog feedDialog = new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(), session, params)
                    .build();

            feedDialog.show();
        } else if (state == SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED) {
            if (checkin != null)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.facebook_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send Facebook Token too

```
String Token = session.getAccessToken();
```

And then

```
    params.putString("token", Token);        
    params.putString("id", USER_ID);
    params.putString("to", "xxxx");
```

It should be works

Comment: mm, it seems logic this way. It shows me a page where i should login(this is wierd and don't think it's ok) and after that "An error occurred. Please try again later."